# Make Flutter Web Sentry error report readable?

Tags: flutter, dart, minify, sentry, flutter-web

Flutter Web error report sent to Sentry is not readable because is minified.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37875
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16883#issue-316793104

I am use: https://pub.dev/packages/sentry

How I can make report not minify so I can read?

Comment: Have you tried uploading sourcemaps? dart2js should output sourcemaps. Try uploading them: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/sourcemaps/

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

When you build your app, use the `--source-maps` option to enable building the source maps:

```
flutter build web --source-maps
```

Then, upload the source maps to Sentry using the [command line interface](https://docs.sentry.io/product/cli/):

```
sentry-cli releases files "myapp-1.0.0+1" upload-sourcemaps /Users/me/myapp/build/web
```

Comment: It will still give me the minified js stacktrace of the app. Do you mind elaborating on this?